# Google API Key for browser. Issue when referrers set

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-console-developer

I generated Browser API Key in Google Console and set referrers:

[image: referrers in google console for my api key]

Then I go to http://afriflirt.com, open JS console in browser and run this code ("Google Maps Geocoding API" enabled for this api key in settings):

```
var apiKey = 'AIzaSyAGpR-mG46fDbmWjJwkZZHft_xvZ_dM3cA';
$.getJSON(
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=12345&key=' + apiKey,
    function(resp) {alert(JSON.stringify(resp));}
);
```

in response I see this message:

> This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API
>   key. Request received from IP address 113.180.75.109, with referer:
>   http://afriflirt.com/

If I remove referrers - API key start working, but this is not safe. 
So it's a problem only when I set referrers. Tried different formats of referrers patterns, but nothing worked. Also tried to wait some time (as I saw "it may take up to 5 minutes for settings to take effect"), but it doesn't help too.

Please let me know if you have any ideas how to fix this.

Comment: it's as if `http://afriflirt.com/` doesn't match any of the referrers you've set up

Comment: You will to consider the note below "Note: It may take up to five minutes to take effect"

Comment: Jaromanda X, Will try with "http://".   gerardnimo, yes I saw it and one time I wait for a day, but it didn't help

Comment: It didn't help too, I added referrers (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1875424/refs.png), regenerated key, wait for 15 min and still get same error. New key is AIzaSyDi0HCEgxo8WMxXKSaMq9gHUf5eRtoIQ5E

Comment: And this is referrer in request to API: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1875424/referer_in_request.png

Comment: Is this a mobile app or a website or both?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key), you need a server key for the geocoding web service.

Create a server key, enable it for IP address: `113.180.75.109`, that should work in your example (but it isn't recommended to use a server key from javascript like that, use a browser key and the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)).

Comment: Thanks, I see "The Google Maps Geocoding API will only work with a Server key.". This is weird that it works with Browser API Key when referrers not set. I can't set certain IP address as I use key from user's browser, so server key will work for me like browser key without referrers. Another solution is to move geocoding requests to server side and filter referrers inside my code.